# Is the numerable product of finite abelian groups a cantor set?

Tags: finite-groups

Today I have heard that statement but I can't find the reference.

Can somebody know a reference and/or a proof?

Comment: Why do you say compact and finite? Surely one implies the other

Comment: Yes you are right. Let me fix it.

Comment: You'll need infinitely many of the groups to be nontrivial. The denumerable product of the trivial group is the trivial group. Also, it seems that the group structure isn't playing any role here, it's just the fact that a denumerable product of finite sets of cardinality $\geq 2$ is homeomorphic to the Cantor space by Brouwer's characterization of it as a compact metrizable totally disconnected space with no isolated points.

Comment: This type of question is more appropriate for math.stackexchange.

Comment: I think I've made this point before, the way to deal with questions that have been posted to MO in genuine error should be to put the questions on hold and not to downvote them. The latter is not a kind thing to do.

Comment: @JamesSmith :  I very much disagree.  When these questions show up on the front page, they deter first-time visitors from coming back.  I believe that's a more-than-sufficient reason to keep them off the front page, and the way to do that is to downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that a base for the product topology can be formed by sets of the following form:

$$U_{\alpha_0,....,\alpha_{n}} = \{(x_i : i \in \mathbb{N}) \in \prod_{i \in \mathbb{N}} G_i : x_0 = \alpha_0, x_1 = \alpha_1, x_2 = \alpha_2 ..., x_k = \alpha_k\}$$

where $\alpha_0 \in G_0$, $\alpha_1 \in G_1$, .... $\alpha_k \in G_k$.

Sets of this form form a tree under the reverse containment relation.

For $\sigma = (\alpha_0,....,\alpha_k)$ and $\tau = (\beta_0,...,\beta_j)$, we have that $U_{\sigma} \supseteq U_{\tau}$ (i.e., $U_{\tau}$ is an extension of $U_{\sigma}$ in this tree of open sets) if and only if $\sigma$ is an initial segment of $\tau$.

The facts that a base for the topology is a finite branching tree and that every two points are separated by the topology together imply that the space is homeomorphic to Cantor space.

The idea of the proof is to construct a map $\varphi$ taking finite binary strings (representing basic open sets in Cantor space) to finite binary strings of elements of the groups $G_i$ in the product. You just want to make sure of the following properties, and then this will give you a homoemorphism by telling you the preimages of all the basic open sets:

(1) If $\sigma \subseteq \tau$, then $\varphi(\sigma) \subseteq \varphi(\tau)$

(2) Every finite string $\tau$ of elements of the groups $G_i$ has $\tau \subseteq \varphi(\sigma)$ for some finite binary string $\sigma$.

(3) If $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are incomparable, then all sufficiently long extensions $\sigma' \supseteq \sigma$ and $\tau' \supseteq \tau$ have $\phi(\sigma')$ incomparable with $\phi(\tau')$

It is an argument by induction to show that such a map exists.